# WS-Security is not working with CXF - endpoint address

Tags: security, cxf

I am trying to add UsernameToken based security in web services written using apache cxf version 2.2.12.

Once I deploy my application in weblogic, I am getting two URL's from which I can access my WSDL.

1. http://localhst:8080/myapp/services/MyService?wsdl
2. http://localhost:8080/myapp/MyService?wsdl

I am trying to consume webservice using soapUI client and problem is If I use 2nd URL, everything works fine, my ejb is getting injected properly etc but WSS4JInterceptor is not getting called at all.

If I change the URL in soapUI to use 1st one, then Interceptor is getting called but then my services is not getting injected and I am getting NULL as service object.

I have configured WSS4JInterceptor in my spring configuration file. I need to call this Interceptor before each request so that I can verify user token from request header.

Here is my beans.xml

```
<bean id="wss4jInConfiguration" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
<property name="properties">
<map>
   <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken Timestamp"/>
   <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText" />
   <entry>
      <key>
         <value>passwordCallbackRef</value>
      </key>
         <ref bean="passwordCallback"/>
   </entry>
</map>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="passwordCallback" class="my.interceptors.callbacks.handlers.PasswordCallbackHandler"/>

<jaxws:endpoint id="myservice" implementor="my.sample.application.MyServiceImpl"
address="/MyService">
   <jaxws:ininterceptors>
       <ref bean="wss4jInConfiguration" />
   </jaxws:ininterceptors>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
  <context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
    classpath:WEB-INF/beans.xml
</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
      </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
      <display-name>CXF Servlet</display-name>
      <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I don't have currently access to my WSDL but here is the  tag looks like.

```
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/MyServiceSoapPort" />
```

Any pointer what i am doing wrong.

NOTE: My services are working fine without call back on URL without /services/

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the Web service is actually deployed twice, once by CXF as configured in your beans.xml file and once by Weblogic as a Java EE 5 Web service. CXF doesn't perform injection (I assume that you are using @EJB), and Weblogic doesn't know anything about your WS-Security configuration.